# how to make unique rule with where() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

hi guys i'm new in laravel and for my question i searched many post but cannot find any solution for that i'm be thankful if you have any guide or solution.

i made a unique rule with where but its not work and return null value so how i do this in right way?

in my case i need to check column 'last_ingameChange' value must lower than time() else validation need to return error message "you just have 1 week to make change your in-game username"

```
public function validator(array $data, array $rules)
{
    return Validator::make($data, $rules);
}

public function updateUserAccount(Request $request, $id)
{

    $rules = [
        'required|min:5|max:255|unique:users,ingame_name,'.$id.'|'.Rule::unique('users')->where('last_ingameChange',  '<', time())
    ];

    $rr = $this->validator([$request->input('ingame_name')], $rules);

    dd($rr);

}
```

but the initialRules is:

```
"ingame_name" => "required|min:5|max:255|unique:users,ingame_name,1|unique:users,NULL,NULL,id"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will simply not work because:

1. You need to provide a validation field
2. The `Rule::unique` will return a `Rule` instance and not a string so you can't concatenate that to another string or you may force it to coerce to a string which will obviously lose any information you had in the where.

You can use an array to contain the rules:

```
$rules = [        
  'ingame_name' => [ //Field name
      "required", 
       "min:5", 
       "max:255", 
       "unique:users,ingame_name,$id", 
       Rule::unique('users', 'ingame_name')
           ->using(function ($q) { $q->where('last_ingameChange',  '<', time()); })
   ]
];

$this->validator($request->all(), $rules);
```

As @MikeFoxtech suggested it is preferable to use a `before` rule however

Comment: ok but this validation always return true even 'last_ingameChange' bigger than time();

Comment: The 2nd validation rule was checking uniqueness of the `id` field since you did not change the default. Also use `using` for complex conditions. Try the update

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id, 'ingame_name')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('last_ingameChange',  '<', time());
})
```

Comment: ok but this validation always return true even 'last_ingameChange' bigger than time();

Comment: @MAXX3 you can make validation **before:date** Example **before:time()** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-before